# How to get size of an directory with lots files with spark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I would like to find the size of hundreds of directories. Within these directories there are tons of files and therefore I would like to do it with Spark (pyspark).

Without Spark it works fine with `os.path.getsize()` but I need a similar function in Spark. So far I have count the number of files sucessfully with the following line of code:

```py
files = spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("/mnt/mal/" + str(i) + "/*.txt").count()
```

Thank for any help!